# If you subclass from dict, why is __dict__ always empty?

Tags: python

I have a question regarding the subclassing behaviour in Python 2.7.

If I subclass from the built-in `dict` type, it seems that `__ dict __` is always empty.
Where does Python save the key/value pairs?

```
>>> class Foobar(dict):
...     pass
... 
>>> foobar = Foobar()
>>> foobar.__dict__
{}
>>> foobar['test'] = 1
>>> foobar.__dict__
{}
>>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A partial answer is that you're misunderstanding the purpose of `__dict__`. `__dict__` is used to store attributes, not items, and it's present in *most* user-defined objects. Indeed, if you subclass `dict` in the appropriate way, `__dict__` *will* have values in it.

```
>>> class Foo(dict):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
...         self.banana = 'banana'
...         self['banana'] = 'not really a banana'
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.__dict__
{'banana': 'banana'}
>>> f.banana
'banana'
>>> f['banana']
'not really a banana'
```

Answer (score 6):

`__dict__` is where an object's attributes are stored.  Dicts' items are not attributes, they are items.  Most dicts have no data attributes.

BTW: subclassing `dict` is difficult to do properly, depending what you are trying to achieve.  For example, you can override its `__setitem__` method, but then `update` won't use it.

Answer (score 5):

The dict class is implemented purely in C as a built-in. Its data storage is private to that implementation.

As a thought experiment, imagine if it put the name/value pairs into a Python dict, how would that dict store them? In another Python dict? And then, well, you get the idea!

Answer (score 2):

Because a dict object doesn't actually have `__dict__` so the `__dict__` you are referencing is the dict local to your object `Foobar`. Because `Foobar` has no attributes `__dict__` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

`__dict__` is for attributes:

```
>>> class D(dict):
    pass

>>> d=D()
>>> d.__dict__
{}
>>> d.x=5
>>> d.__dict__
{'x': 5}
```